# How to Pass JR Bean Data Source only to subreport and JREmptyData Source to master IReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I a new to jasper report and i am not getting how to pass JRBeanCollectionDataSource only to subreport and JREmptyDataSource to master ireport.

I have one java bean class usingbean having properties compet and compet_name with getter and setter methods.

In my master report i have one field name as dataBeanList which is the Arraylist of type usingbean and field property is set to type list.

My subreport is having two fields named as compet and compet_name...

```
   <subreport>
                    <reportElement uuid="0db7b8b7-9cf5-41fc-b271-ffb6333c80f3" x="129" y="30" width="200" height="100"/>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{dataBeanList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
```

My java code is...

```
   try
        {

             Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            newpdftemplate newpdftemplate = new newpdftemplate();
            ArrayList<usingbean> dataBeanList = newpdftemplate.getDataBeanList();

            JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("D:/workspace/itxtgraph/jrxml/FirstReport.jrxml");
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "D:/workspace/itxtgraph/jrxml/");
         jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
        "D:/workspace/itxtgraph/report/SecondReport.pdf");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
}
```

My master report is getting filled but subreport is empty with static texts..
Please tell me where i am doing mistakes

error is:

```
 13 Nov, 2013 4:44:31 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport prepare
SEVERE: Fill 1: exception
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : 
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1577)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:655)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class itxtgraph.usingbean'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:837)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    ... 15 more
```

> why each element of array list is displaying in new page if bean fields are directly taken in main report

Comment: How is the field dataBeanList defined in the main report?

Comment: I set its class as list. Sir, but i have only two string property in bean class

Comment: I need to fill the subreport through bean and master report through empty data source

Comment: I don't see how your main report is being populated if you are passing an empty datasource to it

Comment: My main report does not contain any field...It contains only parameters

Comment: The key line in the trace is:Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class itxtgraph.usingbean' - how have you defined the fields in the jrxml for the subreport?

Comment: @JamesB thank u sir....it worked, i have described the field to _this, so it was showing error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the subreport datasource to the main report as a parameter rather than a field.

Java:

```
...
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
newpdftemplate newpdftemplate = new newpdftemplate();
ArrayList<usingbean> dataBeanList = newpdftemplate.getDataBeanList();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);
parameters.put("subReportDataSource", beanColDataSource);
...
```

JRXML:

```
...
<parameter name="subReportDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
...
<subreport>
    <reportElement uuid="0db7b8b7-9cf5-41fc-b271-ffb6333c80f3" x="129" y="30" width="200" height="100"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
...
```

In your current code, the field dataBeanList is null as you are passing an empty datasource to the main report.

Comment: Sir, by doing this i am not getting values in fields of subreport

Comment: Getting this error of net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please?

Comment: sir, why each element of arraylist is printing on single page if i am not using subreport and putting bean fields directly in main report

Answer (score 0):

List predstave = (List)request.getSession().getAttribute("predstaveR");

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(predstave);
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/Predstave.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
inputStream.close();

response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=PredstaveRezisera.pdf");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,out);
```